# Insertar SELECT en una tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

Estoy tratando de insertar todos los campos con un id en especifico dentro de una tabla, estos datos los obtengo de un select, quiero meterlos en una tabla para poder hacer consultas con los datos de esta tabla como referenica. Esto  es lo que tengo

```js
declare @json varchar(max) = 'esto es un json del diablo'
---SELECT DISTINCT parent_id, NAME, stringValue
--FROM parseJSON(@json) 

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM parseJSON(@json) 
--WHERE parent_ID = 1


select min(parent_id) as p_id 
from parseJSON(@json) 
group by parent_id
having min(parent_id) = max(parent_id) 
order by parent_id
-- hasta aquí todo bien esta consulta me da los ids
-- que existen dentro del json, pero ahora necesito
-- tomar esto valores y agregarlos a idstemp


IF OBJECT_ID('idstemp') is not null DROP TABLE idstemp


CREATE TABLE idstemp(
 id int 
);

 Insert into idstemp
 (id)
 values
 (
 select min(parent_id) as p_id 
from parseJSON(@json) 
group by parent_id
having min(parent_id) = max(parent_id) 
order by parent_id
 )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas hacer un `select into`

En este caso, en sql server se llama “insert into- select”

Crea la tabla y la rellena con el resultado

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/select_into.php

EDIT: revisa bien cómo se escribe, ya que veo que tienes paréntesis anidando la Query etc.

PD; si quieres crear una tabla temporal, puedes hacerlo con la marca #

`Select FieldA...FieldN 
into #MyTempTable 
from MyTable`

Answer (score 1):

En este caso deberás utilizar el `INSERT INTO SELECT` en `SQL SERVER`, mas o menos sería algo como esto:

```
INSERT INTO AEROLINEA
SELECT IDCODIGO, LINEA
FROM AEROCHILE
GO
```

Te dejo un enlace. Saludos

> http://www.respuestasit.com.mx/2015/07/insert-into-en-sql-server.html